# How can I align the pixels with using GDAL and Python?

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp, alignment

I am trying to use Python/GDAL to align different GeoTIFFs that I warped (`gdal.Warp`) to the same SRS. My problem is one of the images is rotated, the pixels do not overlap perfectly, which is something I need.

How can I do this? I am fine with deleting the outermost pixels for resampling, I just do not know how to do it. Here is an example, as you can see the orange one is slightly off (~1.5m in x and y at 10m resolution)

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
    Da = gdal.Open(i)
    Name = i[7:]
    options = gdal.WarpOptions(srcNodata=-1000,dstNodata=-1000,dstSRS="EPSG:32632")
    DB = gdal.Warp(destNameOrDestDS = "Band02/rep_cut/"+Name[:-4] + "_32632.tif",srcDSOrSrcDSTab= Da, options = options)
```

If add `targetAlignedPixels = True` to the options, there is no output at all.

Comment: Warp with target aligned pixels option `-tap`.

Comment: As I am using python I tried to add the option targetAlignedPixels = True to my gdal.WarpOptions call. But it does not work as I get no output at all. I added my code to the question

Comment: Have a look at the autotests in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/utilities/test_gdalwarp_lib.py. There seems to be options and warpOptions.

Comment: I do not really get it, I think that this might only be possible if I merge the data using gdalWarp

Comment: With `-tap` pixels are aligned to the origin of the coordinate system and the option does work also with a single image. I do not really know Python but maybe you are just doing something wrong. The GDAL autotests are run after each commit to the code base and Gdal.warp is also tested with `ds = gdal.Warp('', '../gcore/data/byte.tif', format='MEM', targetAlignedPixels=True, xRes=100, yRes=50)`. Mayby you have a confusion with options and warpOptions `-wo` in https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#gdalwarp, https://gdal.org/api/gdalwarp_cpp.html#_CPPv4N15GDALWarpOptions16papszWarpOptionsE

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I will try again!

Comment: Thank you for the solution! It worked for command line, now I have to either figure out how to do it in python or I just use os.system or subprocess to call the command-line from python.

Comment: Notice that it would be safest to align all the images with -tap but if the other images have their origins already in coordinates which are full pixel widths/heights from (0,0) then they are OK for matching.

Comment: I will just loop through all files to make sure I do not have any misaligned imges. thanks for the hint!